# Powershell foreach loop?

Tags: powershell

I have a powershell script where i first do a invoke rest method to query an API, and then i convert the results to a data result, to finally create variables for the different values.

```
$response = Invoke-RestMethod 'https:....
$response | ConvertTo-Json
$response.Data.result
```

then the variables creation:

```
foreach ($responses in $response ) {

 $task=$response.Data.result.task
 $user=$response.Data.result.user
 $group=$group }
```

The variables result is:

```
$task   $user         $group
task1   user1,user2   group1
task2   user3         group2
```

The goal is for each task to add users as members of Active Directory groups. (ex: add `user1` and `user2` to `group1` and `user3` to `group2`)

What would be the appropriate for each loop to have it working as desired?

Thanks

Comment: What's with all these quotes??